# PLESK and DNS nameservers

Tags: dns, plesk

I'm a bit confused about the setup and would like to ask if somebody could clarify it. I have inherited domain with PLESK panel. These are my DNS ns records:

[image]

Right on top of the screenshot I can see "This server acts as a primary nameserver for the DNS zone". In this case shouldn't NS records point to public IP address of the VPS? They don't and really would like to find out why they point to dns.hospedando.com and not to my the VPS public address if the DNS server runs on Plesk.

Another question is about my domain register page. This is a screenshot:

[image]

In green it says "The zone is active". In order to do some testing I added MX with high priority so later I could do a quick nslookup -type=mx mydomain.com to see if it really is active. It turns out that it isn't and it's pointless to add records in there. What if I'd like to make it active so I can add DNS records in there (in domain register page)?  I'm asking because in long term I'd like to switch off this VPS but doing it I guess I will lose all my DNS records, so I need to transfer them somewhere else.

Comment: Changes to the DNS can take hours to a couple of days to update, so using nslookup, straight after making changes, is pointless. I'm not saying this is the problem, but you can't rule it out either. I would make sure the name servers at the domain registrar match that of the Plesk Server, before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The NS records are and were equal at the domain register and the Plesk Server. I am really confused why NS records points to dns.hospedando.com and not to the public IP address of VPS instance as, per image attached, this is the primary nameserver for this domain. .

Comment: Contrary to what Simon says, you can test changes immediately if you query the appropriate nameservers that is the authoritative ones for the parent zone (at the registry). Also I recommend using `dig`  instead of `nslookup`.

Comment: `NS` records by definition point to names, not IP addresses.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek `Contrary` it's not contrary at all, maybe to the testing method but if the user is wanting to use the website or email, they are subject to dns propagation, dig, nor nslookup, does NOT speed up this process. He/she can, however, use internal DNS changes locally on the machine to access the website straight away.

Comment: You said: " Changes to the DNS can take hours to a couple of days to update, so using nslookup, straight after making changes, is pointless." and this is false. You can use `dig` (better than `nslookup`) immediately after the change, no need to wait for any "propagation"  (which is not the appropriate term anyway). Of course you have to use it appropriately, that is query the relevant nameservers. You were not speaking about real user traffic, but about testing. You do not need to wait to test. You can even test **before** the change, tools like Zonemaster have a "pre-delegation test" option.